# Mongodb nested query retreival

Tags: mongodb, database

In a collection how to find out the nested value.
Suppose the collection have

```
Major
  Minor#1
  Minor#2
     List
        SubList
```

How to retreive the name of the **List**. The name is in all the collection in a database.

Comment: can you please add a sample document structure in question?

Comment: And also the expected result you want to achieve.